# App stuck in review on google play console

Tags: google-play

I have my first app in "in review" status for at least one month. I first sent it to review, and they asked for some change. I made them, and sent it to review, but now it's being stuck for such a long time:

[image]

The app must follow the new process of testing it with at least 15 users, then it's supposed to be eligible to be published. I don't know if I simply have to wait or more actions are needed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Only the people from Google App store will be able to answer your question

Comment: Not sure, maybe there's something I haven't done properly to make them revise the app? If everything looks ok, then I agree with you